ng not found error when building Angular project using dockerfile
I came into a very strange issue yesterday. I have been working on an Angular project and deploying using docker. Everything works fine till yesterday, all of sudden I cannot build the docker image. The dockerfile is:
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve the application with Nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist/gate /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# Copy self-signed SSL certificates
COPY certs /etc/nginx/certs
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

The docker error log is like:

4/6
RUN npm install
14.0s
npm warn deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated read-package-json@6.0.4: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.
npm error Exit handler never called!
npm error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm error <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-18T20_54_10_021Z-debug-0.log
build
5/6
COPY . .
1.0s
build
6/6
RUN npm run build --omit=dev
ERROR
0.0s
> frontend@0.0.0 build
> ng build
sh: 1: ng: not found

Then I check the docker log of successful case, I notice that issue happens in the forth step. The normal log is like:
build
4/6
RUN npm install
16.0s
npm warn deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm warn deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm warn deprecated @wessberg/ts-evaluator@0.0.27: this package has been renamed to ts-evaluator. Please install ts-evaluator instead
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
added 1089 packages, and audited 1090 packages in 15s
120 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
10 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 6 high)
To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix
Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.8.1 -> 10.8.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2
npm notice
build
5/6
COPY . .
8.0s
build
6/6
RUN npm run build --prod
32.0s
npm warn config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
> frontend@0.0.0 build
> ng build
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
â Browser application bundle generation complete.
â Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
â Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
- Generating index html...
2 rules skipped due to selector errors:
.form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
.form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
â Index html generation complete.
Initial Chunk Files | Names | Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.486f9d20944b6cd4.js | main | 1.65 MB | 351.20 kB
styles.b35c1c689cedab16.css | styles | 329.66 kB | 32.46 kB
scripts.1ac6d0d02f230370.js | scripts | 77.70 kB | 20.87 kB
polyfills.4cb30b968c6ea108.js | polyfills | 33.03 kB | 10.66 kB
runtime.f0cd325c9a9e41bb.js | runtime | 988 bytes | 556 bytes
| Initial Total | 2.08 MB | 415.74 kB
Build at: 2024-07-18T13:14:22.046Z - Hash: 52b720b54f35c1fe - Time: 30454ms
Warning: /app/src/app/checklist/checklist-view/checklist-view.component.ts depends on 'moment'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

I have tried many solutions found online but they all don't work. I have tried to clear npm cache, delete node_modules folder, delete package-lock.json, reinstall again using npm install, downgrade npm verstion to 8 even to 6. None of these solved the issue.
This issue comes out of nowhere, I did nothing about the project folder. I could successfully build 5 hours before the issue came.
The version info are
Angular CLI: 16.2.12
Node: 20.15.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.12
@angular/cdk                    16.2.14
@angular/material               16.2.14
@schematics/angular             16.2.12
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3

Warning: The current version of Node (20.15.1) is not supported by Angular.

Can someone help with this?


Your npm install fails. What is the content of your log? /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-18T20_54_10_021Z-debug-0.log

Seems like this is an issue with npm: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7672

@JSONDerulo It makes no sense. I could just run it yesterday. How come does it not work out of nowhere. And I cannot even file the log file.

You are using FROM node:latest. For several reasons, this is bad practice. First, you will get automatically new versions, which may introduce issues like you are seeing. Also, you are using latest Node, so you will get brand new changes which might have bugs in it. Additionally, latest Node is not supported by Angular. I would highly recommend to use LTS Node instead. It would have definitely prevented this issue.

@JSONDerulo OMG! You really are my hero today. I use the Node:lts-slim and it can build now. I have never realized that images in docker hub can cause issues.

You shouldn't use the latest tag of the node image with Angular projects. Angular only supports the LTS version. In the stable channel some changes might be made which Angular first needs to adapt for. Use the lts tag instead:
FROM node:lts


You really saved my day. That is the solution.
